# How can I display the virtual horizon in the viewfinder of my Nikon D7200?

Tags: nikon, camera-controls

One of the exciting possibilities of the Nikon D7200 is that it apparently includes an internal orientation sensor that can check whether you're holding the camera level. Given that roughly 80% of my photos come out wonky, I would *love* to use this in all my pictures!

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to turn it on.

Well, no, I seem to have turned it on in live view; now every time I select live view, the virtual horizon appears. But I can't figure out how to turn it on in the viewfinder. The manual shows where the marks will display, but I can't seem to find a menu item to turn them on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy:

1. Bring up the Camera Menu and under the CUSTOM SETTINGS MENU go to “f Controls”.  Scroll down to “f4 - Assign Fn button”. Press the right arrow button once. You will now see a list of functions available. Select “Viewfinder virtual horizon”. Press the OK button.
2. Your function button is now set to show the virtual horizon tool in the viewfinder. To access it simply press the function button once. In the viewfinder you should now see two scales – one running left-to-right on the bottom of the screen, and on the right side of the screen you should see the same scale running from top-to-bottom. To turn off the virtual horizon press the function button once.

Source: https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-virtual-horizon-feature-two-great-ways-to-use-it

Comment: OK, that's... interesting. I would never have thought of looking in the button customisation menu! So is there some way to turn this on permanently so I don't have to keep pressing the Fn button?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, not that I know of... On my Canon 6D it works pretty much the same way.

Comment: Weird. I wonder why anybody would ever want to turn this off...

Comment: FWIW, I only see *one* level mark. If I hold the camera in landscape orientation, I see the marks along the bottom. If I hold the camera in portrait orientation, I see marks along the side. I assume that's how it's supposed to work on this model.

Comment: no there is no possibility to turn this feature on permanently. and it is also no use to have it on permanently because you check it only fast when framing your composition and for most people it is more important to see the current camera settings like the f stop and the exposure time and this is not visible if this feature is on. if the images are just a little bit wonky it is not a problem to fix it in post and if they are mostly very wonky you should train to make more straight photos without the virtual horizon

Answer (score 0):

yes press the lv button then press info button to cycle through other options to have on your live view screen

Comment: This answer would be better with images depicting the process, if possible.