# How do I enable the virtual horizon option for Nikon D7500 when it is disabled

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-d7500

I used to be able to display the virtual horizon from live view in my Nikon D7500. After a few weeks I tried to use it again but now the option is disabled in the setup menu. It also will not show up if I repeatedly click the info button while in Live View. I think it has something to do with the way my info button is displaying options in my Live View because I thought different options were suppose to be cycled through when repeatedly clicking the info button but now that does not happen either.  I think I must of changed a setting somewhere that has caused this but I have not been able to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display the virtual horizon in the viewfinder of my Nikon D7200?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92899/how-can-i-display-the-virtual-horizon-in-the-viewfinder-of-my-nikon-d7200)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but the article did not solve my problem. I had the virtual horizon working a few weeks ago from live view and was able to toggle access it by cycling through via the information button on the back. But now it the live view display will not cycle through my options so it won't access the virtual horizon.  All it displays now is a title that says "Exposure preview" with a list of icons on the right of the window but nothing for the virtual horizon. The virtual horizon option is also disabled in the menu system.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I miss took the "I" button on the right side of the back as the information button when there was literally a button labeled "Info" on the left side of the back.  I was pressing the "I" button when I should have been pressing the "Info" button.  Pressing the "Info" button brings up the horizon graphic to level the camera.

This solves the problem of getting the horizon graphic to show for insuring the camera is level.  The horizon option in the menu system is still disabled but I don't need that as long as I can pull it up using the "Info" button on the left rear of the camera.